# how to access airflow web UI in python using web browser

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I installed airflow for python. How can i acccess web UI for airflow.

did  type on internet explorer but nothing appears

localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the webserver:

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

Then you will be able to access the UI via `localhost:8080`

You can follow the [quick start](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) instructions.